# hash_set hasher function

Tags: c++, stl

Say I decided that my hasher for hash_set of a series of integer is the integer itself. And also say my integer range is very large, 1-20 and then 1000-1200, then 10000-12000.
e.g.: 1, 2, 5, 7, 1111, 1102, 1000, 10003, 10005
Wouldn't that be a very bad hashing function? How would data be stored by hash_set in this case, by say, the gcc implementation if anyone knows.

### Thanks

EDIT:
Thank you for both replies. I should note that I have already specified my hasher to return the input value. e.g. the hash for 1001 would be 1001. So I ask if the implementation would take liberty to do another round of hashing, or would it see 1001 and the array size would grow to 1001?

Comment: You're saying growing array size to 1001 wouldn't be hashing, or that doing another round of hashing wouldn't be hashing? Didn't understand your point :). Although I would respectfully disagree with it either ways. :)

Comment: I probably just misunderstood the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The hash table would start small, occasionally rehashing to grow when the load factor gets high enough.  Just because the hash value is 12000 does not mean there would be 12000 buckets, of course--the hash_set will do something like "mod" the hash function's output to make it fit within the number of buckets.

The identity function you describe is not a bad hash function for many hash table implementations (including GCC's).  In fact it is what many people use, and obviously it is efficient.  What it would be a bad example of is a cryptographic hash function, but that has a different purpose.

Comment: I agree that identity function can be reasonably efficient, depending on requirements, however, my application requires me to save on space too, so I would want to know if the hasher would do another round of hashing, or would create 1200 buckets.

Comment: As I said it would do something like "mod" your hash function's output to fit it to the range of the number of buckets.  It's hard to say this is "another round of hashing," it's just how hash tables often work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and inputs. I take it that you're assuming this is how it happens (I find it very reasonable though), or is this how gcc or any other implementation does it?

Comment: I'm not assuming, I've looked at GCC's hash table implementations as of versions 4.2-4.4 or so.

Comment: Nice. Thanks. In that case, can you elaborate on how the modulo is applied. (since you say something like modulo, I'm guessing its not exactly modulo) Also how does it decide what number to use for the modulo operation?

Answer (score 0):

Even if your data is clumped in certain ranges within the hash values typically only the least significant bits of the hash of each value will be used to store it. This means that if the bits representing say 0-128 were evenly distributed then your hash function would still behave well regardless of the distribution of the hash value. This does mean however if your values are all multiples of a certain binary value e.g. eight then lower bits won't be so evenly distributed and the values will clump in the hash table causing excessive chaining and slowing down operations.

Comment: Is that how the gcc implementation does it, or are you talking about a general hashing function?

Comment: I was talking about hash functions generally. It is less to do with the function however and more to do with fitting the actual hashed value into the buckets, which may well be smaller than the maximum number expressible by an integer so all implementations will do this step in some way or another.